# Pycharm can't connect to mysql: Access denied

Tags: pycharm

I am working on ubuntu 18.04. My pycharm version is:

PyCharm 2022.1 (Community Edition)
Build #PC-221.5080.212, built on April 12, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.14.1+1-b2043.25 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Linux 4.15.0-175-generic
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 1972M
Cores: 12

Current Desktop: ubuntu:GNOME

When I am trying to connect  with mysql using the following program:

```
import pymysql

conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                       user='root',
                       password='',
                       database='db',
                       charset='utf8mb4',
                       cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
cursor = db.cursor()
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
> File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/pythonProjectDB/main2.py", line 9,
> in <module>
>     cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)   File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/pythonProjectRev/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py",
> line 353, in __init__
>     self.connect()   File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/pythonProjectRev/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py",
> line 633, in connect
>     self._request_authentication()   File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/pythonProjectRev/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py",
> line 907, in _request_authentication
>     auth_packet = self._read_packet()   File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/pythonProjectRev/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py",
> line 725, in _read_packet
>     packet.raise_for_error()   File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/pythonProjectRev/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/protocol.py",
> line 221, in raise_for_error
>     err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)   File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/pythonProjectRev/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/err.py",
> line 143, in raise_mysql_exception
>     raise errorclass(errno, errval) pymysql.err.OperationalError: (1698, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'")
```

My mysql version is:

mysql> select version();

```
+-------------------------+
| version()               |
+-------------------------+
| 5.7.37-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Created databases are:

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| db                 |
| menagerie          |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
```

Somebody please guide me.

Zulfi.

Answer (score 1):

lThe traceback (read bottom-up) error "`raise errorclass(errno, errval) pymysql.err.OperationalError: (1698, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'")`" says that local user `root` was denied access to the database server.

Were you running your queries as `root` or with `sudo`? Why. Don't be confused between the system manager account `root` and the MySql "root" user.

See `https://serverpilot.io/docs/how-to-access-mysql-with-the-mysql-root-user/`and read `man mysql mysqld`.